# Aunque – modo y significado

Tags: subjuntivo

Tengo dos preguntas:

1. > Aunque **quisiera**, no puedo ayudarte.

¿Se puede decir que el verbo “quisiera” expresa el deseo y atenúa el valor concesivo (con sus significados de un obstáculo o un impedimento) en esta frase o me equivoco totalmente?

2. > Aunque me **gustaría** colaborar, no puedo hacerlo.

¿Sería posible utilizar el condicional simple después de *aunque*?

Gracias

Answer (score 3):

Las dos frases son correctas, pero expresan matices de significado distintos:

- Si decimos **Aunque quisiera, no puedo ayudarte**, esto significa "no quiero ayudarte, pero si fuera cierto que quiero ayudarte, de todos modos no podría hacerlo".
- Si decimos **Aunque me gustaría colaborar, no puedo hacerlo**, estamos expresando "quiero colaborar, pero no puedo hacerlo".

Comment: Para mi en primera instancia las dos frases significan lo mismo, pero en el sentido estricto creo que @WildFeather está en lo correcto. Para hacer la primera igual a la segunda creo que tendría que decirse "Aunque quiero, no puedo"